# @font-face rule for Universe 55 font is not working

Tags: html, css, font-face, truetype

In html5 i have used a custom font(Universe 55 font). I downloaded .ttf file,used with @font-face rule & checked with IE,Chrome,mobile browsers. It doesn't work, but in websites they say browsers will support this font-type.
Do i need to use any other file formats for font.

I have used @font-face rule as,

```
@font-face
{ font-family: 'Universe2';
src: url("C:\Users\..\Desktop\Fonts\Univers LT 55 Roman.ttf"); }
.custfont
{ font-family: 'Universe2';
font-size:25px; }
<body><div class='custfont'>This is a customized font</div></body>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to link it from `C:\Users\..\Desktop` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to link it via the project for example your project is at d:/projectname inside you have font file you link it like this in CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('myfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('myfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('myfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Univers LT 55 Roman.ttf in your project...

Comment: after adding how you have refered the path?

Comment: i placed html file in a folder named "myproj". then i added font using src='C:\Users\..\Desktop\myproj\Univers LT 55 Roman.ttf"'

Comment: jjust give src: url('Univers LT 55 Roman.ttf')..no need to add a folder for dat..